How can I get audio on the speakers of my controller
I have NiTHO Hexagon Controllers. They're connected as PS4 controllers in wireless mode and as XBox 360 controllers in wired mode. Through ds4 windows software, I can control the input profile of this controller. For the specifications, I have provided the link for the controllers as well as user manual page.
My question is, how can I get audio on my controller speakers. The speakers are supported only on console. But is there a way to get the audio on the controllers using any third party app (say ds4 windows) or directly. Or maybe when I connect in wired mode.
Controller: https://nitho.com/collections/controllers/products/nitho-hexagon
User Manual: https://cdn.shopifycdn.net/s/files/1/0361/6774/5674/files/MLT-EXAG-K_Manual_EN_IT_-_20230524.pdf?v=1685929832
